# Providing DateTime values in OData

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime, odata

I'm currently writing a special client application to allow our unit tests to work with an OData interface using the XML structure for atom feeds.
All seems to be working properly, but i'm running into trouble when I need to pass a DateTime value as property.

I've written the following code that extracts the DateTime value from the property of the object and stores it in a specific format:

```
private static void GenerateProperty<T>(StringBuilder xml, T obj, PropertyInfo info)
        {
            // Extract the information about the property if it contains a value.
            if (info.GetValue(obj, null) == null) return;
            string type = info.GetGetMethod().ReturnType.ToString().Split('.').Last();
            string value = info.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
            if (type == "DateTime")
                value = ((DateTime)info.GetValue(obj, null)).ToString("yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss");
            if (type == "Boolean") value = value.ToLower();

            // Append the property to the generated XML.
            xml.Append(type.ToLower().Equals("string") ? 
                    string.Format("<d:{0}>{1}</d:{0}>", info.Name, value) : 
                    string.Format("<d:{0} m:type=\"Edm.{1}\">{2}</d:{0}>", info.Name, type, value));
        }
```

The code is heavy on reflection, but that's beside the point. The values returned by this code for a DateTime are in the following format: **2011-49-13T11:49:41Z**

However, i'm receiving the following error from my OData Service:

> Error processing request
>   stream. Error encountered in converting the value from request payload
>   for property 'Created' to type 'System.DateTime', which is the
>   property's expected type. See inner exception for more
>   detail.   
>       The string '2011-49-13T11:49:41Z' is not a valid AllXsd
>   value.
>       System.FormatException
>          at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s,
>   XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Parsing.WebConvert.StringToPrimitive(String text,
>   Type targetType)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Serializers.PlainXmlDeserializer.ConvertValuesForXml(Object
>   value, String propertyName, Type typeToBeConverted)

So apparently it doesn't understand the DateTime format, but when I look at the documentation that's posted here: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/overview#AbstractTypeSystem

I'd expect it to be valid. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Your code isn't outputting a `Z` AFAICT but your error message definitely seems to imply that your actual code is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`

should be

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: For completeness: in case you also need fractional seconds and/or time zone offsets, use something like `2016-04-30T23:59:59.999+02:00`. make sure to escape the 'plus' if sending this in an URL: `2016-04-30T23:59:59.999%2B02:00`

Comment: Isn't the correct answer `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`? With a 'Z' at the end?

Comment: @krlzlx That should be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 5):

**ToString("O")** will solve the problem too.

Comment: This does not actually work. When uploading, I get an error, most like due to all the extra digits that it doesn't support.